# Passing parameters between pages in Windows Phone 8 using SQL server compact

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, windows-phone-8

I am trying to pass parameters from my main page to another page but I have no idea what variable should i put. For an example

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ToDoDetailPage.xaml?detail" + **variable** , UriKind.Relative));
```

I am using SQL Server compact 3.5 and I want to get the data selected and passing it to another page. What should replace for that variable as now its just an empty variable. Here is my code that I have done:

*MainPage.xaml.cs*

```
namespace PhoneApp
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the LongListSelector control to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    // Load data for the ViewModel Items
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }

        using (DatabaseContext c = new DatabaseContext(DatabaseContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            c.CreateIfNotExists();
            c.LogDebug = true;
            //output todolist data from database
            MLongListSelector.ItemsSource = c.ToDoList.ToList();
        }
    }

    // Handle selection changed on LongListSelector
    private void MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If selected item is null (no selection) do nothing
        if (MLongListSelector.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        // Navigate to the new page
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ToDoDetailPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        // Reset selected item to null (no selection)
        MLongListSelector.SelectedItem = null;
    }

   private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var si = MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem as PhoneApp.ViewModels.ItemViewModel;

        if (MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        if (si.LineOne.Equals("+ To Do List"))
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/todolistPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        else if (si.LineOne.Equals("+ Reminder"))
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/reminderPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        // Reset selected item to null (no selection)(//important)
        MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem = null;
    }

}
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="today">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PivotItem>



        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="activities">
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Hello" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PivotItem>

    </phone:Pivot>
```

Below is the image of the breakpoint

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to pass the `selected` element to `another page`. If so, then try this :

```
var select_Item = companyAppList.SelectedItem;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PageName.xaml?Select_Item="+select_Item.Text, UriKind.Relative));
```

and you can retrieve this parameter like this:

```
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Select_Item"))
{
    TextBlock1.Text = NavigationContext.QueryString["Select_Item"];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have a red underline under MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem; it says cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An expected conversion exist(are you missing a cast?). Am I missing something here?

Comment: Its fine i cast it to string using ToString(). I am testing out the code now.

Comment: Hi, I think it works. But what should i put in my ToDoListDetail.xaml to display the details? Thanks

Comment: @GeneLim Ok you need to find select items

Comment: @GeneLim You could put a textblock and set the value to that textbloxk

Comment: I have already put a textbox. how do i setit to the value to it?

Comment: try this: `if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Select_Item"))
{
    textblock1.Text = NavigationContext.QueryString["Select_Item"];
}`

Comment: Hi, it works but it gets a wrong data. The output is PhoneApp.ToDoList. How can i get a specific data from the specific row of the table?

Comment: There is an error stating that the type or namespace name 'ToDoItem' could not be found.

Comment: I think i need to put something like PhoneApp.something. Inside my DatabaseContext.cs has DebugWritter, DatabaseContext and ToDoList. I have tried PhoneApp.ToDoList but some output appear. Is there something I missed? Thanks

Comment: @GeneLim See my edit. when you debug it you will get list. try to debug

Comment: what is companyAppList refer to? because the error says it does not exist in the current context

Comment: I am still new here I am sorry. but what should I do to debug it?

Comment: Search on Google. set break point on this line `var select_Item = companyAppList.SelectedItem;
` and debug it by press `f11`

Comment: I think I have done it. It gives SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Description]
FROM [ToDoList] AS [t0]
-- Context: SqlProvider(SqlCE) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: System.Data.Linq, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24eec0d8c86cda1e

Comment: From all the discussion it works well thanks! I will open a new question for the break point. Sorry for the trouble and thanks